Is keeping Apple Pencil 2nd Generation docked always good for pencil's battery?
I use an back-case for my iPad Air which also has a Pencil holder and at the same time pencil is attached magnetically to the iPad. Most of the time the battery of Pencil is at 100%
Is keeping pencil docked always good for Pencil's battery?
Does iPad's battery drain faster than usual when charging Pencil?

People do say it is better for a battery to max it at 75% charge, but for a Pencil, this would be a lot of hassle, and not worth the time. Keeping the battery at 100% is not going to destroy your battery; it was built to be charged to this percentage.
The iPad battery is used to charge the Pencil, and it will drain a little faster. It will technically drain the iPad battery a small amount if you keep it docked past 100%, but not enough to notice. I don't know what other options you have for charging the pencil, and for most people the small percent loss (my guess 1 or 2%) from the iPad to the battery usually isn't a big deal.
